# read.table function in R drops elements

Tags: r, comments, read.table

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [cannt read file with “#” and space using read.table or read.csv in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12771522/cannt-read-file-with-and-space-using-read-table-or-read-csv-in-r)

I have the problem with R that when I'm reading in (using `read.table` function) delimited files (e.g. tab-delimited text files) with R, the rows containing `#` or `'` characters are silently dropped. how the file should be read in so that the rows containing these characters aren't dropped?

Comment: Read the help for `?read.table` and then change the `comment.char = "#"` argument.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12771522/cannt-read-file-with-and-space-using-read-table-or-read-csv-in-r

Comment: also don't forget `quote=""` to take care of the `'` characters

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default `comment.char` is the `#` character. You can change this using the `comment.char` argument, i.e.

```
read.table(file, comment.char="@")
read.table(file, comment.char="##")
```

Comment: The problem is that I would need to ignore both # and ' at the same time.

Comment: You can feed `comment.char` a vector: `comment.char=c("#", "'")`

Comment: as I said above, you probably need to use `quote=""` to get `read.table` to ignore single quotes (')

Comment: @DrewSteen Actually Drew, putting an array results in an invalid comment.char argument error. This feature would be beneficial. I have the problem of a flat file which is 90% space-separated numeric, with a few comments scattered here and there. The comments aren't preceeded with something standard such as # or %, it is surprisingly difficult to handle. I wish I could put an array into this containing every letter of the alphabet, but it doesn't work. I cant believe this F**kwits that provide data that don't consider the people that have to analyse it....